# CSS Image Border

Tags: css, border

Probably a simple question this, but...

I can apply CSS to all images using img {} in the CSS.

Some of the images have a border specified in html (e.g. border="1") - from a WYSIWYG editor.

So, is there any way to specify in CSS that if the a border is specified, then it should be white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border:1px solid white;` or `border-color:white;`

Here, the official specs. Probably more than you want to know, but this is the formal reference. If other documents disagree, this is the authoritative one.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#border-properties

Oh, and the HTML attribute `border="1"` is deprecated. Better use CSS all the way.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be simple - img {border-color:white;}

Comment: I think it is supposed to be conditional. IF it there is a border, it must be white, in your case ALL will be white.

Comment: Hm? If there is no border, does it matter if it's white or not?

Comment: if you want conditional, you should be able to do this `img[border=1]{border-color:white;}`

Comment: The original question was not specifically for an 1px border (it said "if they have a border" and only mentioned "1" and an example. So the better condition would have been `img[border] {border-color:white;}`. But then, as I said, it doesn't matter, because if there is no border, setting the color to white doesn't have an effect!

Answer (score 1):

As there is CONDITION of IF border specified so

```
border:1px solid white;
```

would be wrong and instead mention only border color using property as

```
border-color:white;
```

It will just set border color but not set border width as required.